# Проблема с соединением базы данных MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Всем добрый денб. Возникла проблема при запуске программы. Работал со своей бд mysql, как только поменял данные на другую базу данных, то возникла ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 606, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/iljal/PycharmProjects/projects/old_pro.py", line 21, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 265, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 960, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 288, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 608, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '78.155.220.225:3306' (10061 Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Собственно в ошибке все сказано, на указанном IP нет MySQL на порту 3306 или до него не дает добраться фаервол

Answer (score 1):

Перепроверьте логин и пароль к вашей базе данных, а также драйвер по которому вы подключаетесь к ней